# How do I limit the number of results for a specific variable in a SPARQL query?

Tags: query-optimization, sparql

Let's say I have a SPARQL query like this, looking for resources that have some shared property with a focal resource, and also getting some other statements about the focal resource :

```
CONSTRUCT {
  ?focal pred:icate ?shared .
  ?other pred:icate ?shared .
}
WHERE {
  ?focal pred:icate ?shared ;
         more:info ?etc ;
         a "foobar" .
  ?other pred:icate ?shared .
}
LIMIT 500
```

If there are more than 500 other resources, that `LIMIT` might exclude that `more:info` statement and object. So, is there a way to say *"I only want at most 500 of `?other`"*, or do I have to break this query into multiple pieces?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `LIMIT` in subqueries, i.e. something like the following:

```
CONSTRUCT {
  ?focal pred:icate ?shared .
  ?other pred:icate ?shared .
}
WHERE {
    ?focal pred:icate ?shared ;
           more:info ?etc ;
           a "foobar" .
    { 
      SELECT ?shared {
        ?other pred:icate ?shared .
      }
      LIMIT 500
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-sparql11-query-20120105/#modResultLimit

> The LIMIT clause puts an upper bound on the number of solutions
>   returned. If the number of actual solutions, after OFFSET is applied,
>   is greater than the limit, then at most the limit number of solutions
>   will be returned.

You can only limit the number of solutions to your query, not a specific subset of it. You can use a subquery with a `LIMIT` clause though: http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql-features/#Subqueries.